# How to disable a particular standard button in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

I am working on python application where I have created the dialog which includes several standard buttons like: Reset, OK, Cancel, Apply.
here is the relevant code for the standard button,

```
self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(ROI)
self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Reset|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Apply|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
self.buttonBox.setObjectName( ("buttonBox"))
```

My question is how to disable only Apply button
Even I tried the following code

```
QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Apply.setEnabled(False)
```

but getting error

```
AttributeError: 'StandardButton' object has no attribute 'setEnabled'
```

So how do I disable particular button in set of standard button

Answer (score 2):

@Omkar's comment as answer:

You need to find the specific object and then call its `setEnabled()` method with `False` as parameter.

For your `QDialogButtonBox` you can get to the specific button via

```
btn_apply = self.buttonBox.button(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Apply)
```

and then disable using

```
btn_apply.setEnabled(False)
```

Alternatively this can be done in one step:

```
self.buttonBox.button(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Apply).setEnabled(False)
```

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#button for a reference on the button "retrieval" and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enabled-prop for the disabling.

Answer (score 0):

i have not used it very extensively but think there can be one solution

try using .setVisible kind of api if you can find from readthedoc website for pyqt

Comment: I got the solution just followed this code btn = self.buttonBox.button(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Apply)
        btn.setEnabled(False)

Comment: It is necesary to Import QDialogButtonBox. And it seems in QT5 this is in QtWidgets, not in QtGui. So, it works if `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialogButtonBox` is present.

Comment: @Omkar Your method in the comment worked for me. Maybe you could add it as an answer.